# Validation rule help - After Stage passes

Tags: validation-rule

I want to enforce my users to fill out two fields but instead of making those fields compolasory at the start I want to create a validation rule so when the Opportunity passes a stage they have to fill out those two filed.  This is what I have at the moment.

```
AND( 
    RecordTypeId, "Medical Opportunity",
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "PreCheck Interest"),
    ISBLANK(DealerReseller__c),
    ISBLANK(DealerResellerContact__c),
    ""
)
```

`DealerReseller__c` and `DealerResellerContact__c` are both lookup fields.  For some reason I can't use StageName in this Validation Rule.

**FIXED - WORKS**

```
    AND (
OR(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Strong Interest'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Confirmation'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Convinced'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Order In'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
 ),
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Medical_Opportunity",
    ISBLANK(DealerReseller__c),
    ISBLANK(DealerResellerContact__c))
```

Comment: If you're getting an error message (and you should be getting one in this case), then it's _always_ a good idea to include the error message, verbatim.

Comment: Also, is this a validation rule on `Opportunity`, or is it on some other SObject?

Comment: Error: Field StageName is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. Tell me more   Yes this is for Opportunity Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things wrong here

- You have an empty string at the end of your `AND()` The `AND()` function can only take boolean arguments, so this is wrong
- `RecordTypeId, "Medical Opportunity",` is not how you check the record type. `RecordTypeId` is, unsurprisingly, an `Id` and not a string. Even if it were a string, you're not doing a comparison here

If this is a validation rule on `Opportunity`, then you should be able to fix it by addressing those two issues.

- The blank string at the end should be completely removed
- You need to check if `RecordType.Name` is equal to "Medical Opportunity" (or if `RecordType.DeveloperName` is equal to "Medical_Opportunity". The developer name is like the api name for fields in that spaces (and other special characters) are converted to an underscore)

There's possibly a third issue, which I may have changed in my edit to your question. The original part involving the stage name was `ISPICKVAL(StageName > "PreCheck Interest"),`. If that was intended, then that is *also* an issue.

Formulas cannot get information about what position a particular picklist value is (in relation to the other available/active picklist values). If you want to include multiple stage names, you need to either:

- do `ISPICKVAL()` checks for each individual picklist value (and stick them all into an `OR()`)
- Use `CASE()` to return, say, `1` when it matches one of your target values

e.g.

```sql
/* A single picklist can only hold one value at a time */
/* So if you want to say "Is this picklist any one of these values?" */
/*   then you need to use an `OR()` (which returns true if any part of it */
/*   results in true) */
OR(
    ISPICKVAL(MyPicklist__c, 'Value 1'),
    ISPICKVAL(MyPicklist__c, 'Value 2'),
    ISPICKVAL(MyPicklist__c, 'Value 3')
)
```

```sql
/* An alternate solution is to use CASE() */
/* CASE() can't return true/false directly, so we need to return something else */
/*   and then do a comparison to get a true/false value */
CASE(
    MyPicklist__c,
    'Value 1', 1,
    'Value 2', 1,
    'Value 3', 1,
    /* The default value (required) if we don't find any matches */
    0
) = 1
/* If The picklist contains Value 1, 2, or 3, we'll get 1 = 1, which is true */
/* Otherwise, we'll get 0 = 1, which is false */
```

Comment: `AND (
OR(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Strong Interest'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Confirmation'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Convinced'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Order In'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
 )
    RecordType.DeveloperName,"Medical_Opportunity",
    ISBLANK(DealerReseller__c),
    ISBLANK(DealerResellerContact__c))`  

Error I am getting is:   Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: @QuangoBruce That error is misleading. You're actually missing a comma instead of a closing brace. If you haven't done so already, using wordpad/notepad or something a bit more advanced like notepad++ or vscode to format your formula according to best practice (put each and/or/ispickval/isblank onto separate lines, indent an extra level every time you encounter an open parenthesis) is always a helpful step to help make issues like this easier to find.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have that formatted as you said but the comment section here ran it in one line.  I'm not sure where the comma goes.

Comment: I added it formatted to the initial question

Comment: @QuangoBruce The comma is missing after the `OR()`, and you're still not doing the recordtype check correctly. Like I said in my answer, you need to _do a comparison using the equals operator_.